# Is it possible to make Idle time befor exit my program?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

Is it possible to make Idle time befor exit my program ?

I made Windows mobile C# program and i want that after 5 minut's -

if the user not press any key or tap the screen, the program will exit.

how I can make it ?

thank's in addvance

Answer (score 8):

start a timer when the user clicks on something (or presses a button) Set the timer interval to 5 minutes. Hook an function to the tick event.
In that function call Exit().
On every user input restart the timer

```
Timer Clock=new Timer();
Clock.Interval=5*60*1000;
Clock.Start();
Clock.Tick+=new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);

 public void Timer_Tick(object sender,EventArgs eArgs)
 {
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit()
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

- Create a one-shot timer for 5
  minutes;
- re-arm the timer on every
  user action
- exit program on
  expiration.